# Sign rule for finding the adjugate of a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse, matrix-calculus

So i have this matrix

A= $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 0 \\
    -2 & -5 & 2 \\
   1 & 4 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

And i want to find the inverse of it. Following all the calculations, i get that the determinant is 1 and that the adjucate of the matrix by creating the matrix of co factors is

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -23 & -9 & 6 \\
    8 & 3 & -2 \\
   -3 & -1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
I checked the answer on the answer sheet and it's right.

And i would be happy to end the excercise here BUT if i remember correctly shouldn't i apply the sign rule?

I always thought that after having calculated the matrix, i apply the sign rule which would be

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    + & - & + \\
    - & + & - \\
   + & - & + \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

If i apply the sign rule, then my matrix would look different:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -23 & 9 & 6 \\
    -8 & 3 & 2 \\
   -3 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and ,in order to finish the calculations, i would need to multiply the adjucate by 1 over the determinant of A which is 1.

So i would multiply 1 times each entry in the adjugate and the matrix would still be

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -23 & 9 & 6 \\
    -8 & 3 & 2 \\
   -3 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Which, as you can clearly see, is not the correct answer.

So my question is , should i apply the sign rule? Should i not? What is it that i'm doing wrong? SHould i stop when i just find the adjugate and multiply the entries by the determinant ?

Thanks for the help!

(please do not tell me to find the inverse another way , thanks)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve already applied the sign rule when you calculated the cofactors.

For example when you calculate the $(1,1)$ element, you do:

$$M_{1,1}=\det\begin{pmatrix}-5&2\\ 4&3\end{pmatrix}=-23$$

And when you calculate the $(1,2)$ element, you do (*note the negative sign!!*):

$$M_{1,2}=-\det\begin{pmatrix}-2&2\\ 1&3\end{pmatrix}=-((-2*3)-(1*2))=8$$

Then to get the adjugate you take the transpose of the cofactors.

You’ve done everything correctly and incorporated the sign rule. No need to apply it twice.

Comment: Thank you !! I greatly appreciate your simple, straightforward answer .